# objectjquery ajaxUPD success returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have created a function called **save** , when i call **save** function, I am getting success undefined or object Object

UPDATES:
updated to get he values jqxhr object that ajax returns

```
function save() {
 return   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "foo.json",
        data: json_data,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

            $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>').insertBefore('#form');

        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


        }
    });


}


$(document).ready(function () {

$(function () {
 $("#save").click(function () {
     var jqxhr = save();
     alert("success " + jqxhr.success);
     alert("status " + jqxhr.status);
     alert("status " + jqxhr.readyState);
 });
});


 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ninja edit by OP*
<strike>First of all, there is no `return` statement within your `save` function, so it works as expected by returning `undefined` value.</strike>

Secondly, it won't work that way. You need to return the `$.ajax` call (which itself, returns a `jqXHR object`, where you can hook in and setup code for different events. Afterall, by default an *Ajax request* runs *asyncronously*.

**in save()**

```
return $.ajax({ ...
```

**and later...**

```
save().done(function( retValue ) {
    alert('success ' + retValue);
});
```

Learn more about *jQuerys Ajax* and *Deferred objects* [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: @Neal: there still might be good reason to hook into the request from somewhere else too.

Comment: Mehh. (some text to fulfill the minimum text requirements)

Answer (score 5):

For the upteenth time.

ajax is asynchronous.

Use a callback function.

Comment: how do i go about using a callback function here? can you show me an example in relation to this?

Comment: _Your success function is already a callback_... a silly one at that.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is causing the issue, as i see you are having 2 document ready handlers one in another.

```
/***/
 $(function () { // <--------------------I think this doesn't has to be here, 
                 //                      so remove it and try if this solves 
                 //                      the issue
     $("#save").click(function () {

         var success = save();
         alert("success " + success);

     });
 }); // <-------------------------------and this one too
```

Comment: Neah. Without .ready wrapper, the code will fail if the save button is appears _after_ this script tag in the HTML source.